# I want my button to be click once and i want to disable double click

Tags: android

```
package com.example.shery.tictactoe;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    Button btn1,btn2,btn3,btn4,btn5,btn6,btn7,btn8,btn9;
    TextView tv1,tv2;
    String field1 = tv1.getText().toString();
    @SuppressLint("CutPasteId")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        btn1 = findViewById(R.id.btn1);
        btn2 = findViewById(R.id.btn2);
        btn3 = findViewById(R.id.btn3);
        btn4 = findViewById(R.id.btn4);
        btn5 = findViewById(R.id.btn5);
        btn6 = findViewById(R.id.btn6);
        btn7 = findViewById(R.id.btn7);
        btn8 = findViewById(R.id.btn8);
        btn9 = findViewById(R.id.btn8);
        tv1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv1);

        if (field1.equals("Turn X")){
            tv1.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
        }else if (field1.equals("Turn O")){
            tv1.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
        }

        btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if(field1.equals("Turn X")){
                    btn1.setText("X");
                    tv1.setText("Turn O");
                } else {
                    btn1.setText("O");
                    tv1.setText("Turn X");
                }
            }
        });
```

I want my button to be click once and I want to disable double click so what will be method of doing this and how to do that in my code and want to stop double clicking this is my code below you can check. I want my button to be click once and I want to disable double click :

Comment: Do you want to disable clicking altogether after the first click? Can it be clicked sometime later again?

Comment: yes i want to do that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just call `view.setEnabled(false);` in your onClickListener to disable the view after the first click.

Comment: If i understood it correctly, I don't think he wants to disable clicking altogether, I think his question was more around - If i receive two click events in a short period of time (i.e. a DoubleClick), how do I ignore the second event.

Comment: actually i want to make a tik tac toe game thats why i havebeen asking you i dont want to be click again

Comment: Well you could do it with setEnabled(false) or setClickable(false) as mentioned in the above answer.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, you want to disable de double click on the button. This is not possible because Android queues the clicks, but there's a trick I always use: Storing the last time it was clicked:

```
private long btn1ClickTime= 0; //local variable declaration


findViewById(R.id.btn1).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() - btn1ClickTime< 1000){
            return;//do nothing
        }
        btn1ClickTime= SystemClock.elapsedRealtime();
        //write your code here
    }
}
```